# Is there a way to programatically create a Mobile Project for ArcGIS for Mobile?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-mobile

I need to build a tablet application using ArcGIS Runtime for Windows Mobile. Is there a way to create a mobile project usable by the ArcGIS for Mobile app without having to use the Mobile Project Center?

I need to be able, with a single click, to generate a shapefile (or pgdb), convert it to a mobile cache and be able to generate a mobile project out of it.

Comment: Use the 'Create Mobile Cache (Mobile)' http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003z00000005000000

Comment: +1 This creates the Mobile Cache, but not the entire project

Answer (score 1):

**Create Mobile Cache (Mobile)**

*This tool creates a mobile cache with a map schema and GIS data for Mobile Project Center (MPC), a component of the ArcGIS for Windows Mobile product, to build a mobile project. Using the map document's current full extent, this tool generates a mobile cache from an input map document. **The output is a folder using the map document name as its folder name, a mobile cache containing a map schema, the GIS data, and associated attachments folder (if available).***

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003z00000002000000

Comment: That's good, but this creates only the mobile cache needed to create a mobile project, not the project itself as the Mobile Project Center app does